# Internal DVD player is not recognised

Tags: 11.04, 64-bit, dvd

Having trouble with my DVD player, sometimes it plays and sometimes the system doesn't even recognize that it's there. It ran fine under Windows. I'm running 11.04 64bit (it is a 64bit system) this is the info that came up when I ran "sudo lshw" for the player.

```
*-cdrom
             description: DVD-RAM writer
             product: DVD A  DH16ABSH
             vendor: ATAPI
             physical id: 1
             bus info: scsi@5:0.0.0
             logical name: /dev/cdrom
             logical name: /dev/cdrw
             logical name: /dev/dvd
             logical name: /dev/dvdrw
             logical name: /dev/scd0
             logical name: /dev/sr0
             version: YA12
             capabilities: removable audio cd-r cd-rw dvd dvd-r dvd-ram
             configuration: ansiversion=5 status=nodisc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm running Ubuntu 11.04 64bit, I have Thunderbird 5 installed through the stable PPA. I also had the add-ons "Ubuntu Unity Messaging Menu Integration 0.6 and Unity Launcher Integration 0.4" installed on my system. When I removed these add-ons (because they weren’t doing anything) I regained use of my DVD player.